# One DataAdapter, two different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, join

I find it really hard to explain what is going on, I'll try my best.
We need to make a really simple browser with really simple Favorites + History capabilities, and to do that we need to import them both in a DataSet and use them from there.

The knowledge that I have should be enough, but I would really like to do it more efficient en cleaner. In the database I have 3 tables, one for users, one for favorites and one for history, this is linked with FK's etc. I want a query that returns me every Fav + History url that a user has saved. This is what I have now:

```
SELECT u_id, u_user, h_url, f_url FROM Users, Favorites, HistoryWHERE u_id = h_id AND u_id = f_id AND u_id = 1
```

This isn't the result I'm looking for, I want to fill 2 comboboxes, one with favorites and one with history that both are from the person that is logged in at that moment.

I know this should work with join but inner and outer both give to little or to many results, and left and right join don't seem to work for me either, but I cant explain why. :p I'm semi-new to joins btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want two simple queries, one for favorites and one for history.  Both queries just need to have a `where` clause limiting the user for whom the results are returned.

```
SELECT f.url
FROM Favorites f
WHERE f.userID = 1

SELECT h.url
FROM History h
WHERE h.userID = 1
```

Comment: I know this, I also made it work like this. But why fetch 2 different results if you can put it into one query? The whole idea is to do it with one request.

Comment: @Gideon, why make one complicated query that won't ever do quite what you want, when there are two simple queries that do exactly what you want? What's the issue with having two requests? In your example you'd have to separate the results from a single request anyway, but after having gone through the trouble of uncomfortably forcing them together in the first place!

Comment: Hmm ye, that seems right. Thought it would slow down the whole thing, but guess that isnt true?

Comment: @Gideon, are you having performance problems?  Allow me to paraphrase Donald Knuth, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil!"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate two comboboxes, I would suggest that you retrieve two separate lists, one for each combobox. Then you can bind each list separately to its combobox.

While DataSets may not be the best choice, I think they will work for you in this situation. Your objective will be to write two SQL statements, one for each list. Then, you put the query results into DataTables which are contained in one DataSet. A DataTable can be boung to a combobox.